# How can I extract nodes in a nested XML?

Tags: sql-server

Imagine I have following XML:

```
declare @Products_XML xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Products>
    <Product ProductCode="100">
        <Serilas>
            <Serial>
                <YearNumber>2020</YearNumber>
                <SerialNumbers>1,2,3,4,5</SerialNumbers>
            </Serial>
            <Serial>
                <YearNumber>2021</YearNumber>
                <SerialNumbers>6,7,8,9,10</SerialNumbers>
            </Serial>
        </Serilas>
    </Product>
        <Product ProductCode="200">
            <Serilas>
                <Serial>
                    <YearNumber>2021</YearNumber>
                    <SerialNumbers>600</SerialNumbers>
                </Serial>
            </Serilas>
    </Product>
</Products>'
```

I want to extract products based on serial numbers, so I should have two rows for `ProductCode = 100` and one row for `ProductCode = 200`, but it only returns two rows.

```
select
        Product.value('@ProductCode','varchar(50)') AS ProductCode
        ,Product.value('(Serilas/Serial/YearNumber)[1]','int') AS YearNumber
        ,Product.value('(Serilas/Serial/SerialNumbers)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SerialNumbers
FROM
@Products_XML.nodes('/Products/Product')AS TEMPTABLE(Product)
```

The result will be:

```
ProductCode | YearNumber  | SerialNumbers
-----------------------------------------
100         |   2020      | 1,2,3,4,5
-----------------------------------------
200         |   2021      |   600
```

I know it has something to do with [1] in `Product.value()`, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: "so I should have two rows for ProductCode .......but it only returns two rows."   Can you please add expected output? because currently it is pretty unclear what you want/need.

Comment: I expected 3 rows, two for `ProductCode = 100` and one for `ProductCode = 200`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe (I am just guessing here(, you are looking for this:

```
select
        Product.value('.','varchar(50)')  as SerialNumber,
        Product.value('../YearNumber[1]','int') as Year,
        Product.value('../../../@ProductCode','varchar(50)') as ProdcutCode
FROM
 @Products_XML.nodes('/Products/Product/Serilas/Serial/SerialNumbers')AS TEMPTABLE(Product);
```

output:

| SerialNumber | Year | ProdcutCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1,2,3,4,5 | 2020 | 100 |
| 6,7,8,9,10 | 2021 | 100 |
| 600 | 2021 | 200 |

Comment: I accepted the edit, which was done because the XML changed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.nodes` twice, once for `Product` and once for `Serial`

```sql
select
     Product.value('@ProductCode','varchar(50)') AS ProductCode
    ,Serial.value('(YearNumber/text())[1]','int') AS YearNumber
    ,Serial.value('(SerialNumbers/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS SerialNumbers
FROM @Products_XML.nodes('Products/Product') AS x(Product)
CROSS APPLY x.Product.nodes('Serilas/Serial') AS x2(Serial)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c4abbd2fc76350f81120c5747d55ff1)

Comment: Did you try it? Something seems to be wrong since it returns three rows, but value in `YearNumber` and SerialNumbers columns are null.

Comment: Sorry fixed now